# How to reduce the branch divergence of binary search using CUDA

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

The application is to intersect two sorted list of integers (set intersection), say list1 and list2.

Each element of list1 will be assigned a GPU thread, and do binary search to check whether it appears in the list2. It is easy to see that there will be huge amount thread divergences in this application. I wonder if there is any good approach to reduce thread divergences. I am using CUDA to implement this application.

I know there is an approach called P-ary search, but my task is to reduce the thread divergence of binary search. Also I know there is library called thrust, but it seems there is no attempt on reducing the divergences.

Comment: How big are the sets of integers?  On divergences, merging two lists of length `n` involves `O(n)` comparisons, each of which will create a divergence.  I think that you have to accept that you will have a lot of divergences, and then keep them short.  (A bigger challenge is making sure that you load blocks of memory in parallel.)

Comment: i agree - memory access is a bigger problem that divergence.  you've got two source of divergence as far as i can see - the binary search step and termination.  you don't care much about termination, since those threads are done anyway, and the binary step in a loop is only an if/else updating an index.  much much worse than that is the fact that you're going to be reading from all over the place in the second list.  i guess sorting both lists first might help a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both lists are sorted, binary search is not the best algorithm you can do.  Binary search will give `O(n lg n)`, but just doing a merge-like algorithm, only taking intersections, is `O(n)`.

This is a silly algorithm to use a GPU for.  The only case I see is that you've just generated the data in the GPU.  In which case, you want to break the problem up into a bunch of smaller intersections and assign a thread to each.

To do that, pick `k` equally-spaced elements of list1 and find them in list2 using binary search.  Similarly, pick `k` equally-spaced elements of list2 and find them in list1.  You now have `2k` ranges in each list, where each range has at most `N/k` elements.  Now intersect those ranges in parallel.  (Set `k` to be half the number of threads you want.)

Comment: Why you search from the second list in the first list?

Comment: You want to make sure that each sublist has at most N/k elements.  If you picked splitting points from just one list, the subrange from the other list may be too large.

Answer (score 2):

Posible code:

```
    bool end = false;
    bool found = false;

    while(!end && !found)
    {
            int diff        = max-min;
            int middle      = min + (diff / 2);

            end             = diff < 1;
            found           = element[middle] == element;
            if (index < elements[middle])
                    max = middle-1;
            else //(index > elements[middle+1])
                    min = middle + 2;
    }
    return found;
```

Warning: this code could generate exception by access out of range memory